# How to solve app crashing while using multidex and google analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, native, android-multidex

I have applied multidex and Google Analytics in my app. The app is crashing in pre-lollipop devices. I have tried to change the versions of multidex also but nothing worked. The app crashes on starting the app itself.
This is my gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/yongjhih/android-gradle-plugin.m2/raw/master/' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.infstory.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'cn.fanrunqi:waveprogress:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex

        // optional
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString() // enable the main-dex-list
        dx.additionalParameters += '--minimal-main-dex'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my Application class:

```
package com.package;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;


import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;


public class AnalyticsApplication extends android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication {

    private static GoogleAnalytics sAnalytics;
    private static Tracker sTracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

       sAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    }

    /*@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }*/
    /**
     * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
     * @return tracker
     */
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        if (sTracker == null) {
            sTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }

        return sTracker;
    }
}
```

I have used the application in manifest as:

```
<application
        android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: where's the log?

Comment: It would help if you could share the error logs

Comment: @ShinilMS The device is not with me so I am unable to get the logs. I am using marshmallow and it is working fine in that but not in kitkat or jelly bean.

Comment: How can we help without seeing any log?

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens when your app exceeds the dex limit..

try to enable this

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

then in your dependencies at below

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

finally in your Application class

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

if you dont want to use multidex, you need to avoid of the use of unnecessary dependencies.

the use of exclude module is needed to reduce dex size
for example:

```
compile ('com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: I have done this. But still the problem is coming in pre-lollipop devices.

Comment: remove this compile 'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'

Comment: I have been compiling the app without this at that time also the app was crashing. I tried to add this line but is of no use.

Comment: the problem is I don't have the logs as it is being tested on the device that is not with me.